# issues after uninstalling reticulate: loadNamespace(name)

Tags: r, ubuntu, reticulate

I uninstalled reticulate due to some error I was getting with Altair but now everytime I start R I get this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘reticulate’
```

I already tried to reinstall reticulate but I get a:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘reticulate’
Calls: .First ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘reticulate’
Calls: .First ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reticulate’ had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried to reinstall jsonlite but it shows me the same error.

Any ideas of how to solve this issue without deleting - reinstalling everything?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

R version 3.5.1

R Studio Server 1.2.1181

Anaconda build py36hbbc8b67_0

Comment: Are you loading a restored work space? Have you set up a `.Rprofile` script to run when you start R automatically?

Comment: wow... such an easy solution. You were right. Deleted my .Rprofile and now it works! Thanks